# why is django import export not working for me

Tags: django, django-import-export

I have the following model for a website category

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True ,related_name='sub_categories')

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="created at")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="updated at")
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "category"
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"
        db_table = "website_categories"
        unique_together = ('name', 'parent',) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have installed django-import-export model and have the following set up for the admin

```
from .models import *
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class WebsiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("url", "category", "user")
    search_fields = ["url", "category", "user"]

class ServiceCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name",)
    search_fields = ["name"]

class ProductCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name",)
    search_fields = ["name"]    


class CategoryResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description',)


class CategoryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name",)
    search_fields = ["name"]   
    resource_classes = [CategoryResource]


admin.site.register(Website, WebsiteAdmin)
admin.site.register(ServiceCategory, ServiceCategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(ProductCategory, ProductCategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

On the admin side I see the import and export buttons and I am able to import a file but the data is not getting correctly imported and the only thing getting generated is the id. So for every line in the csv doc the id is generated bu not the name nor the description is being imported.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong pls?

Here is the csv file shortened:

```
eCommerce,A website for online buying and selling products,,
Business,A website for promoting and conducting business activities,,
Blog,A website for publishing articles stories and posts,,
Portfolio,A website showcasing an individual's or organization's work,,
Event,A website for promoting and managing events,,
Personal,A personal website for individuals to share their interests and content,,
Membership,A website with restricted access for members only,,
Nonprofit,A website for nonprofit organisations to promote their cause,,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your csv is invalid, try this:

1. Add a header with the correct column names.
2. Remove field 3 which is empty
3. Add id field - since you declare this in `fields` the import process will expect it to be there.  Note I have picked default ids, but these should match internal ids if you want update logic to work (otherwise it will create duplicates).  Since you define 'name' and 'parent' as unique together, you could use these instead of id, although obviously a foreign key reference to 'parent' will need to be in the feed.  See [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#create-or-update-model-instances).

Example:

```
id,name,description
1,eCommerce,A website for online buying and selling products
2,Business,A website for promoting and conducting business activities
```

[Docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#importing-data)

Comment: Thank you this solved it I was under the impression if you do not have a value for field you should put a comma.

Comment: glad that worked... Number of fields must match number of columns, but if there is an empty field it can be indicated as 0 length - e.g. ',,'